# Gorm - Has One relation with anonymous field

Tags: go, go-gorm

I use Golang and GORM.
I have a `User` structure which has one `Association`.

```
type User struct {
    ID       int
    ...
}

type Association struct {
    ID       int
    UserID   int
}
```

I also have an `AssoUser` structure, which is composed of a anonymous field `User`, and has a pointer to `Assocation`.

```
type AssoUser struct {
    User
    Asso *Association
}
```

When I run

```
var assoUser AssoUser
assoUser.Asso = &Association{
   Name : "asso_name",
   ...
}
assoUser.Name = "user_name"
...

// filling the struct
db.Debug().Create(&assoUser)
```

I expect it to create the `User` AND the `Association`, but it only creates the User.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: can you show code for ... filling the struct ...?

Comment: I've edited the code

Comment: I fill all the structure except id's, it should be filled by gorm

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, but I discovered it was an issue with anonymous types.

If you have

```
type Thing struct {
    Identifier string
    ext
}

type ext struct {
    ExtValue string
}
```

gorm won't be able to find `ext`, so it won't appear in the table at all.

However, if you have

```
type Thing struct {
    Identifier string
    Ext
}

type Ext struct {
    ExtValue string
}
```

`ExtValue` will appear in the table as a normal string, as if it were a part of the `Thing` object.

If you want to make a has-one relationship, you have to include an id in your struct.  So the above example would look like this:

```
type Thing struct {
    Identifier string
    Ext
}

type Ext struct {
    ThingId  uint
    ExtValue string
}
```