# Defining Belongs To relation for anonymous field using GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

I wanted to create relationnal database structure in a using the go package Gorm.

I wanted to add foreign keys to my structure, it works perfectly on regular field, but it does not seem to work when I want to make foreign key for anonymous fields.

Here is some simplified code to demonstrate my case

```
type StructA struct {
    gorm.Model
    SimpleFieldID int     // appears in database as foreign key
    SimpleField   StructB
    TranslationID int     // appears in database as a regular int
    Translation
}

type StructB struct {
    gorm.Model
    SomeField      string
    SomeOtherField string
}

type Translation struct {
    gorm.Model
    En string
    Fr string
}
```

I wanted to have anonymous field in the first place to be able to call some GetName() method on any object that has the Translation attribute.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40721475/gorm-has-one-relation-with-anonymous-field), but the given anwser was for the has-one relation, where I want to use a belongs-to relation.

Comment: First of all, it called embedded, using this is not the same as belongs-to relation

Comment: After realising that the fields from Translation are actually copied in the StructA table, it makes totally sense why the TranslationID foreign key doesn't work. I am new to Go, so I didn't know that fields from anonymous fields are embedded inside the struct.